# Is there any way I an delete more than 20k mutation in Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I have millions of records in Spanner table and I would like to delete rows from Spanner using some query condition. For Eg: delete from spanner table where id > 2000. I'm not able to run this query in Spanner UI, because of Spanner 20k mutation limit in single op's. So is there any way I could delete this record from spanner table by doing some tweaks in api level code or do we have a work around for this type of use-case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use gcloud command line as :

```
gcloud spanner databases execute-sql <database_id> --instance=<instance_id> --enable-partitioned-dml --sql="delete from YourTable where id > 2000"
```

NOTE: SQL query must be fully [partitionable and idempotent](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-partitioned#partitionable-idempotent)

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation [Deleting rows in a table](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/modify-mutation-api), I think you should consider Particioned DML execution model:

> If you want to delete a large amount of data, you should use
>   Partitioned DML, because [Partitioned DML](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-partitioned) handles transaction limits
>   and is optimized to handle large-scale deletions
>
> Partitioned DML enables large-scale, database-wide operations with
>   minimal impact on concurrent transaction processing by partitioning
>   the key space and running the statement over partitions in separate,
>   smaller-scoped transactions.

[image]

Comment: I'm doing partitioned DML for a bulk delete and I'm getting the limit saying I'm doing too many mutations at once

Comment: It's not mentioned in the doc. But it was because I was deleting a table with interleaved tables. I had to remove rows from interleaved table before deleting the parent table.